# React using graphQL apollo refetch will also update other components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graph, apollo

I'm using react and Apollo.
I am using refetch in the ProgressBar, which is updated every 3 seconds.
I'm using refetch to update every 3 seconds, and the same screen is being updated by a different component, MemoBox.
I am using refetch in the ProgressBar, which updates every 3 seconds.
I do not want MemoBox to update every 3 seconds.

```
import {useInterval} from 'beautiful-react-hooks';

const ProgressBar = () => {
  const {userId} = useParams<{userId: string}>();
  const {data: {user = null} = {}, refetch: refetchUser} =
    useUserQuery({
      variables: {uuid: userId},
      skip: !userId,
    });
  if (!user) return null;

  useInterval(() => {
    refetchUser();
  }, 3000);

  return (
     <p>{user.percent}</p>
  )
}
```

```
const MemoBox = () => {
  const {userId} = useParams<{userId: string}>();
  const {data: {user= null} = {}} = useUserQuery({
    variables: {uuid: userId},
    skip: !userId,
  });
  return (
    <Memo dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: user.memoHtml}} />
  )
}
```

```
const Box = () => {
 const {userId} = useParams<{userId: string}>();
 const [status] = useQueryParam('status', StringParam);
 const {data: {userId= null} = {}} = useUserQuery({
    variables: {uuid: userId},
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    skip: !userId 
    },
  });

  if (!userId) return null;

  return (
   <>
   <MemoBox/>
   <ProgressBar/>
   </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Please share the code structure where those two components are used.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: Will using refetch update other components?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an option into the the progress call to useUserQuery like this

```
const { {data}, refetch: refetchUser} = useUserQuery(
  { variables: { ... },
  {fetchPolicy: "no-cache"}
)
```

It should not update the cache.  Thus it should not update other components.
You'd have to play around with it.

Here are the docs on the fetchPolicy

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies